# Find the UMVUE of $U(n_1,θ)$ where $θ>n_1$

Tags: self-study, sufficient-statistics, umvue

> Let $X_1,X_2,\dots ,X_n$ follows $U(n_1,θ)$ where $θ>n_1$ and $n_1\le n$.  Find the UMVUE of $θ$.

My answer is: $$\frac{(n+1)X_n}n - \frac{n_1}n$$ 
Is that correct?

Comment: Try creating a sample and see if your estimator makes sense.  For example, set $n_1 = 100$, $n=2$, and $x_1 = 102, x_2 = 110$.  What do you get?

Comment: This question has the `[self-study]` tag, & states the OP's attempt to solve the question. I think this meets our standards & can stay open.

Answer (score 0):

The UMVUE of $U(0,θ)$ is $(n+1)x_n/n$ where $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ follows $U(0,θ)$. Let $Y_i=X_i-n_1$, then $Y_i$ follows $U(0,ɸ)$. Then the UMVUE of $ɸ$ is $(n+1)Y_n/n$ where $ɸ=θ-n_1$.

\begin{align} \newcommand{\or}{{\rm or}}\newcommand{\(}{{\big{[}}}\newcommand{\)}{{\big{]}}}
& &E\((n+1)Y_n/n\) &= ɸ  \\[5pt]
&\or, &E\((n+1)(X_n-n_1)/n\) &= θ-n1  \\[5pt]
&\or, &E\((n+1)(X_n-n_1)/n +n_1\) &= θ  \\[5pt]
&\or, &E\((n+1)X_n/n-((n+1)n_1)/n+n_1\) &= θ  \\[5pt]
&\or, &E\((n+1)X_n/n -n_1/n\) &= θ  \\[5pt]
\end{align}

Hence the UMVUE of $θ$ is $(n+1)X_n/n - n_1/n$.

Comment: I edited your post to use the $\LaTeX$ formatting the site affords. I think it makes it more readable. Please ensure it still says what you wanted it to.